# Assign value to new object via destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

How to assign to Object via destructuring? For example

```
let parameter = {id : 10, username : 'john'}
let obj = {}
({id : obj.iduser, username : obj.user} = parameter)
```

Expected :

```
{iduser : 10, user : 'John'}
```

But, i got an error :

```
ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

Reference : [Exploring.JS - ES6 [ #10 - Destructuring ]](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

Comment: do you want a new object or just two variables with the content?

Comment: new object @NinaScholz. I know, if just with variable i don't using `let obj = {}` but i just using `let {id : iduser, user : username} = parameter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminating the `let obj = {}` line with a semicolon solves this:

```js
let parameter = {id : 10, username : 'john'};
let obj = {};
({id : obj.iduser, username : obj.user} = parameter);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is correct ! Thanks :3 But I don't get it, why without semicolon ruined everything? I think JS will fine without semicolon?

Comment: There are some edge cases in which a semicolon is required for the browser to interpret the code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could destuct first and use shorthand properties for a new object.

```js
let parameter = { id : 10, username : 'john' },
    { id: iduser, username: user } = parameter,
    obj = { iduser, user };
    
console.log(obj);
```