# Javascript destructuring and assignment into new object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Lets say I have an object:

`let x = {a:1,b:2,c:3}`

Now I can destructure as follows:

`let {a,b} = x;`

Is it possible to assign, (in the same line as the destructuring) these into a new object, the equivalent of?:

`let newObject = {a,b};`

or (in pseudocode, I realise this doesn't work)

`let newObject = {a,b} = x;`

or would I be required to use something as lodash `_.pickBy` function?

`let newObject = _.pickBy(x,['a','b'])`

The reason I am asking is, I would like to do something like that for functions signatures:

```
let fun = ({a,b}) => {
    let args = {a,b}; // <---- 
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use this `let newObject = {a : x.a, b : x.b};` ?

Comment: Same line! `let { a, b } = x, newObject = { a, b };`

Comment: @MikeM yep, i get that, but If I have lots of variables it gets tedious.

Comment: @TusharShahi yeah, that works but Unfortunately I really want this for function signatures where i can say declare a function `fun = ({a,b}) = {...}`, and assign all the arguments into a single object.

Comment: `fun = ({a,b}) => {let newObject=arguments[0]}`

Comment: but.. how big is that argument part.. the `({a,b})` part i mean

Comment: Your `fun` works you know, if you include the `=>`.

Comment: @bombsquad, sometimes 10 or more arguments, if I am using it to create database documents.

Comment: I'd say that _.pickBy seems the best choice

Comment: I feel like you’re trying to make code more succinct, but it will just end up being confusing and less readable. Sometimes verbosity is not a bad thing

Comment: @SethLutske No i'm just tired of writing many variables twice, it feels like unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible, because, while looking the same, the destructuring assignment and object syntaxes are completely different things.

```js
let a, b;
{a,b} = x  <-- {a,b} is not an object
```

If you try returning the result of destructuring assignment, it will still be returning `x`, the full object.

```js
const result = {a,b} = x 
// `result` is the full object
```

or

```js
const result = ({a,b} = x);
// `result` is the full object
```

Anyway, writing such one-liners could be extremely confusing to teammates. It would raise my eyebrows during a peer review anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to filter the object by key without middle variables.

Here is my solutions:

```js
let x = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
let y = {}
;({a: y.a, b: y.b} = x)
```

```js
let filterObjectByKeys = (object, keys) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, object[k]]))
let x = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
let y = filterObjectByKeys(x, ['a', 'b'])
```

Reference:

1. [Assign value to new object via destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230674/assign-value-to-new-object-via-destructuring)
2. [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)